# Ansible URI Output

Tags: linux, rest, ansible

I'm running a playbook to store the output of a uri call and only print one portion of the json.

```
        
    - name: check result
      uri:
        url: "{{ item.json.link.href }}"
        force_basic_auth: yes
        validate_certs: no
        user: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        body_format: json
        return_content: yes
      register: result
      with_items: "{{ this.results }}"
      no_log: True
    
    - name: print result
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.json.deploymentState }}"
      with_items: "{{ result.results }}"
```

For each item in the loop though I receive output

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'content': ' .....
    "msg": "SUCCESS"
}
```

The information after .... is the full content of the REST API call which I cannot post here but it is not needed in terms of printing when the playbook is run and distracts the user from the msg portion.  Is there a better way to parse this?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to limit the output from loops. See the [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#id15) on that.

Example:

```yaml
    - name: print result
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item.json.deploymentState }}"
      with_items: "{{ result.results }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.json.deploymentState }}"
```